# secure spark standalone user/rest api interfaces, as much as possible

Tags: security, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to secure, as much as possible, spark standalone user/rest api interfaces.

For the browser application Web UI and REST API (port 4040), I added authentication screen with Java servlet filter.

I can’t find more instruction for adding authentication screen for Standalone Master Web UI and REST API (port 8080) or for Standalone Worker Web UI and REST API (port 8081).

More over, I notice that I can configure connections to those interface via https. I tried to configure ssl by the instruction in [Spark Security Standalone mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#standalone-mode) and I configure parameter spark.ui.https.enabled to true without success.

When I connect to https://:8080, the browser show ne this error:

Firefox: “An error occurred during a connection to :4040. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG”

And in pyspark log I see:

WARN HttpParser: Illegal character 0x16 in state=START for buffer HeapByteBuffer@4364d580[p=1,l=171,c=16384,r=170]={\x16<<<\x03\x01...\x00}

WARN HttpParser: badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x16 for HttpChannelOverHttp@1fe4f33{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}

Do you know where can I find more clearly instruction?

And if I enable https, how can I disable http?